# GraphQL: Argument on InputObject has an invalid value ([\"a\"]). Expected type '[Bars!]!'. How to pass enum to GraphQL query in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have this in my code:

```
# spec
let(:query) do
  graphql_query_for(:foos,
                    {
                      foo_bars:      [:a],
                    },
```

And

```
module Types
  module Arguments
    class FoosInput < Types::BaseInputObject
      argument :foo_bars, [Types::Enums::BarsType], required: true
```

And

```
module Types
  module Enums
    class BarsType < Types::Enums::BaseEnum
      description 'List of different types of bars'
      convert_enum Foo.bars
    end
  end
end
```

And

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  enum bar: {
    a:       'a',
    b:       'b',
    c:       'c',
    d:       'd',
  }
end
```

How do I get the spec to pass, how do I properly send in the enum as an argument to the GraphQL query?

I tried doing `foo_bars: [Foo.bars['a']]`, but similar error.

I would like `foo_bars` to take an array of the enum `Foo.bars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, pass the enum key as all caps symbol, so in this case `:A`.